# Mule Error: Test connection failed: Could not obtain connection from data source - Apache Ignite IMDB

Tags: java, mule, ignite, anypoint-studio, mule-esb

I receive this error while testing the connection with Apache Ignite IMDB Database config, where url is set to "jdbc:ignite:thin://127.0.0.1" and Driver class name : "org.apache.ignite.IgniteJdbcThinDriver".

Detailed error looks as follows:
[image]

So what's the possible solution for this error ?

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation**

This mule error is related to org.mule.tools.maven, as the yellow highlighted line in above screenshot is telling. There is an artifact called ***mule-maven-plugin*** which is not able to access the class ***org.apache.ignite.IgniteJdbcThinDriver*** in the ***ignite-core*** jar. So we need to tell the org.mule.tools.maven that look into ***ignite-core*** jar also during testing.

**Solution**

Open the pom.xml and adjust your plugin section as follows

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.mule.tools.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>mule-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${mule.maven.plugin.version}</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
        <sharedLibraries>
            <sharedLibrary>
                <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
                <artifactId>ignite-core</artifactId>
            </sharedLibrary>
        </sharedLibraries>
        <classifier>mule-application</classifier>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

As you see I mentioned ***org.apache.ignite*** as shared library under plugin section for ***org.mule.tools.maven***.

Well this will elevate the tooling exception error, which occur frequently in Anypoint Studio.